# How to develop software for the Commodore 64 with VICE?

Tags: commodore-64, emulation, software-development

I see a very large fan-base and hear a lot (especially here on retrocomputing) about how great the Commodore 64 was. Growing up in the Windows 95/98 era, I seemed to have missed a great era for computing and was wondering what might be the best way to experiment with the Commodore 64. I honestly don't see myself finding a physical one (unless that's what needs be), so how would I use an emulator (such as VICE) and start programming for the Commodore 64?

Comment: 1. To me, `How to get started with Commodore 64?` is way too broad of a question.  What are you looking to do with it?  Gaming?  Evaluating software or hardware?  2. `so would my best bet be with emulators` to give you an emulator recommendation, we need to know more about what system you plan on running the emulator on.

Comment: I just want to poke around with the terminal interface really. If I had to choose, probably evaluating software and hardware. I want a comprehensive experience.

Comment: @JAL I modified my question. I hope that helps gauge an answer.

Comment: I suggest heading over to the Lemon64 forums for questions like these.  http://lemon64.com

Comment: @RetroGamer Adding more sub-questions without removing others tends to make questions _broader_, not narrower. I think the title is the only place a broad question is left, however.

Comment: Thanks @wizzwizz4. I think I have narrowed-down my question and description to what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an example of minimalistic IDE for C64 development, you'll need just cross-assembler like [ACME](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acme-crossass/) and your favourite monospace text editor. Quite useful and detailed C64 doc is [this one](http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/cbm/c64/vic-ii.txt). VICE emulator you've mentioned has some extensive debugging capabilities and is also cross-platform.
There are also myriads of C64 programming resources around, as there are some complete cross-IDEs for the development. I won't mention any specific ones since I've never dug that deep.

Comment: I actually think that kickass is the best 6502 Assembler

Comment: And I would suggest `ca65` from the [`cc65`](https://cc65.github.io/cc65/) project -- it allows easy modular structure because it comes with a linker designed to work for C programming (and can export lables in `vice` format for easy debugging). Just for completeness :)

Answer (score 5):

The absolutely minimalistic approach would be to just start the Commodore 64 emulator, the C64 then greets you with its starting message and a blinking cursor. Here, you can already start programming in BASIC. There are many tutorials out there for programming the C64 in BASIC, for example [here](https://twobithistory.org/2018/09/02/learning-basic.html).

When you want to write more performant programs, you either need to learn 6502 Assembler or use C. Please note that with C you will be still a bit limited on what you can achieve, but if you already know C programming, it is probably a good compromise. For programming in C, look out for [cc65](https://www.cc65.org/), which is a cross-development tool: you write and compile your code on the PC and then open the compiled program with the emulator.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend:

[KickAssembler](http://www.theweb.dk/KickAssembler/Main.html#frontpage)

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) with the KickAssembler package.

[C64Debugger](https://sourceforge.net/projects/c64-debugger/) for running and debugging the code.

It takes a smallish bit of setup but it's excellent overall.

[image]